# Finite group $(G, \cdot)$ and H a subgroup of G. Prove that if $x \notin H, y \notin H$ then $xy \in H$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Given the finite group $(G, \cdot)$ with $2n$ elements, $n \in N^*$ and also H a subgroup of G with $n$ elements.

Prove that if $x \notin H, y \notin H$ then $xy \in H$.

I'm not really sure how to do this since I've barely started working with subgroups. Could I have some hints on how to approach this type of exercise? Thank you.

Comment: You forgot an important assumption in the title: $(G:H)=2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any subgroup of index 2 is normal, so that the factor group $G/H \simeq \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: My class hasn't yet covered the topic of normal subgroups(and this is part of my homework). Perhaps it could be done another way as well? Anyway I can look that up and figure out how to solve this with your method. Thanks.

Comment: You are very welcome